# Validate that ALL radio buttons are selected or NOT on button Click

Tags: javascript, html, validation, dom, radio-button

I am very new to Javascript and I have this Javascript function that is called on button click. What I want to do is show an alert if ALL the radio buttons have NOT been selected wether they are Yes or No and if they have ALL been selected call another function called addPoints() below.

```
function validateForm(){

    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
       var  formValid = false;
       for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
           if(inputs[i].checked){
               formValid  = true;

            }
       }
      if(!formValid ){   
           alert("Please answer all questions!");
       }

else{

addPoints();

}
}
```

Below is how my radio buttons are presented

```
<form name="form1" id="form1">
<input id="rdo1" type="radio" name="q1" value="10">Yes<br>
<input id="rdo2" type="radio" name="q1" value="0">No
</form>

<form name="form2" id="form2">
<input id="rdo3" type="radio" name="q2" value="10">Yes<br>
<input id="rdo4" type="radio" name="q2" value="0">No
</form>

 <form name="form3" id="form3">
<input id="rdo5" type="radio" name="q3" value="10">Yes<br>
<input id="rdo6" type="radio" name="q3" value="0">No
</form>

<button type="submit" onclick="validateForm()">Score?</button>
```

If I do not select any radio button when the page loads and I call the function validateForm() using the button the message is correct and states "Please answer all questions". If I select either YES or NO from any group it calls the addPoints function. I only want it to call that function when ALL either Yes or Nos have been selected from All radio groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/xtDrL/1/)

#### Code:

```
function addPoints() {
    alert("Adding points");
}

function validateForm() {

    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]'),
        // An empty array
        checker = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].checked) {
            // Whenever find a checked element, push it in checker array
            checker.push(true);
        }
    }

    // Since, there are only 3 radio groups, according to OP,
    // call addPoints when all 3 (yes/no) have been selected
    if (checker.length === 3) {
        addPoints();
    }
    // Show an alert if none has been selected
    else if (checker.length === 0) {
        alert("Please answer all questions!");
    } else {
        // Add something you may want
    }
}
```

Comment: I made a slight alteration but this guided me in the right direction many thanks! 13 being how many groups I have. if (checker.length === 13) {
        getScore();
    } else{
        alert("Please answer all questions!");
    }

Comment: @AlexMcPherson Great to know I was of help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating through each radio button, iterate through each form, and in each from, iterate through the radio buttons

Comment: Would this make a difference to the logic or is this just tidier?

Answer (score 0):

You Can do it using Jquery Like this I used Check Boxes :)

```
function validateForm(){

  if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length != $('input[type="checkbox"]').length){
               alert("Please answer all questions!");
        }else{
               alert("ok!");
     }
}
```